# Como evitar utilizar el tipo de dato var en Asp .Net MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, estructuras-de-datos

tengo la siguiente duda y quiero saber si me pueden ayudar a aclarar esa duda, resulta de que hoy en dia en ASP .NET MVC5 se utiliza mucho el tipo de variable `var` que es una variable que se adapta al tipo de datos mas conveniente, pero quiero saber como puedo evitar utilizar este tipo de dato debido a que primero el compilador tiene que adecuar esa variable a tipo de dato que devuelte la expresion,

Gracias

Comment: La mejor manera de evitarlo es poniendo el tipo de dato que le corresponde.

Comment: @Phi y si en dado caso no se el tipo de dato que me va a devolver algunas consultas que realice como sabre que tipo de dato es el que le corresponde

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera ya depende de ti el saber o no que tipo de variable es, pero es la única manera de no hacerlo. Si es un desarrollo viejo debes investigar como esta definida la estructura y si es tu proyecto debes llevar el control de tu desarrollo.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo lo que pasa es que quiero saber porque el var primero tiene que adaptar al tipo de dato que retorna la expresion y como sabes eso es tiempo de compilacion

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera en ese caso entonces deberías hacer uso de los datos genéricos para evitar entrar en temas de tipos de dato, además que ayuda a la reutilización de código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se usa var para ser mas rapido al codificar... pero lo puedes usar normal con su tipo de datos

```
var cliente = new Cliente();
```

seria:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

var result = new List<NombreUsuario>();
```

seria:

```
List<NombreUsuario> usuarios =  new List<NombreUsuario>();

var edad = 40;
```

seria:

```
int edad = 40;
```

Comment: Var tambien se usa en los casos en que se devuelven objetos anonimos, no es solo para que sea mas rapido codificar. Gracias por la respuesta, como futura referencia podrias mirar [answer]